# How to set max_connections when installing webhook telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, webhooks

On the ms windows command line, you can install:

`curl -F "url=https://логин:пароль@адрес_сервера" https://api.telegram.org/botТокенБота/setWebhook -k`

How to set the max_connections option?

123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567889012345678901234567890

Comment: Try this; `https://api.telegram.org/bot<your_token>/setWebHook?max_connections=123456`

Comment: doesn't work like that

Comment: just removes the webhook